# How to set time for 15 seconds

Tags: timers

When user used one password after close the servo the password will valid for 15 seconds then it will not work. Other 9 will be same process

Here is code I need just this to set

```
int locker = 13;
int lockerState = 0;
const int buzzer = 49;
String readString;

#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo;
int pos = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(locker, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  myservo.attach(9);
}

void loop() {
  lockerState = digitalRead(locker);
  while (Serial.available()) {
    delay(3);  
    char c = Serial.read();
    readString += c;
  }

  if (readString.length() >0) {
    Serial.println(readString);
    if ((readString == "2028") || (readString =="1234") || (readString =="1294") || (readString =="4795") || (readString =="5651") || (readString =="7616") || (readString =="5648") || (readString =="1487") || (readString =="7095") || (readString =="2554"))
    {
      digitalWrite(locker, HIGH);
      for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) {
      myservo.write(pos);
      delay(30);
      }
      delay(5000);
      digitalWrite(locker, LOW);
      /* for (pos = 180; pos >= 1; pos -= 1) {
      myservo.write(pos);
      delay(30);
      } */
      readString="";
    }
      /* else if (readString == "proceed") {
        digitalWrite(locker, HIGH);
        for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) {
        myservo.write(pos);
        delay(30);
        }
      digitalWrite(locker, LOW);
      readString="";
      } */
      if (readString == "decline") {
         digitalWrite(locker, HIGH);
         for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) {
         myservo.write(pos);
         delay(30);
         }
      digitalWrite(locker, LOW);
      readString="";
      }

    else {
      tone(buzzer, 500);
      delay(1000);
      noTone(buzzer);
      delay(1000);
      readString="";
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In programming, there are many cases where designing data structures is
more important than the code itself. Once you have a data structure that
makes sense, the code flows very naturally. I think this is one of those
cases, so let's start by looking at what data you have to store for each
of your passwords:

- the password itself (let's call it the *code*)
- whether it has ever been used and, if so, whether it has expired
- if it has been used but has not expired yet: when it was used for the
  first time

This can be saved in an object with the following data fields:

```c++
const char * const code;
enum { UNUSED, USED, EXPIRED } status;
uint32_t first_use;  // valid if status == USED
```

Now think about what kind of *actions* you want to perform on such a
password:

- you want to be able to test whether it matches some user entry
- you want check whether it can be used and, if so, take note that it is
  being used

Based on these requirements, I propose the following class:

```c++
const uint32_t PASS_LIFE_TIME = 15000;

class Password {
public:
    Password(const char *c)
        : code(c), status(UNUSED) {}
    bool matches(const char *entry) {
        return strcmp(code, entry) == 0;
    }
    void update() {  // expire if it needs to be
        if (status == USED && millis() - first_use > PASS_LIFE_TIME) {
            status = EXPIRED;
        }
    }
    bool use() {  // returns true on success
        if (status == UNUSED) {
            status = USED;
            first_use = millis();
        }
        update();
        return status != EXPIRED;
    }
private:
    const char * const code;
    enum { UNUSED, USED, EXPIRED } status;
    uint32_t first_use;  // valid if status == USED
};
```

Now you need to store all the passwords in an array, and a couple of
functions to operate on the password collection as a whole:

```c++
const int PASS_COUNT = 10;

Password passwords[PASS_COUNT] = { "2028", "1234", "1294",
    "4795", "5651", "7616", "5648", "1487", "7095", "2554" };

void update_all_passwords()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < PASS_COUNT; i++)
        passwords[i].update();
}

// Returns true on success, and uses the matching password.
bool try_entry(const char * entry)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < PASS_COUNT; i++)
        if (passwords[i].matches(entry))
            return passwords[i].use();
    return false;  // no match found
}
```

The function `update_all_passwords()` is meant to be called on each
iteration of `loop()`. It may seem superfluous, as a password is updated
whenever you try to use it. However, without regular updating, a used
password could be reused 49.7 days later, because of the `millis()`
rollover.

Now, in your program, you just need to:

1. Put a call to `update_all_passwords()` at the beginning of `loop()`
2. Replace the big condition that tests for a valid password by
   `if (try_entry(readString.c_str()))`

Comment: Good answer! I would add, that it is not a good practice to use `delay()`. I think it's worth mentioning, that the coding style from the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example is way better (which you already used in your code, but the OP didn't), and will help especially when adding more functions to the code.